# Comment 'Duplicate of' shown on wrong question on Area51 proposal

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close, area-51, duplicate-questions

Today, I got the scare of a lifetime: A notification for a comment underneath [my proposed question](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118029/sociology-and-anthropology/118262#118262) on the Sociology and Anthropology proposal that said my question was a duplicate of another question.

After having calmed down and performing a careful examination though, no close-vote seems to be present on my question. There's another question a few positions down that indeed seems to be an [exact duplicate](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118029/sociology-and-anthropology/118109#118109). That one also does have 2 close-votes currently, closing it as 'duplicate of.." but no comment:

[image]

So, I'm guessing this is a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Even users without close vote privileges can flag for duplicates (and thus generating that comment automatically). Also the comment can be give manually completely even if the OP didn't use the flagging feature.

Comment: Huh? So it's normal that someone votes to close a question that's not mine, but I get the notification + comment? I think I've been around SE long enough to realise that that's not how it's supposed to work, unless this person really wanted to play a joke on me and posted the comment underneath my question :/

Comment: It could have been a mistake of that OP. I don't see a clear relation with that other question close voted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Area 51 does not have automatic duplicate commenting. The user who left that comment typed it in manually; it wasn't added as a result of an automatic process.

There is no bug here. Everything is working as intended.